# Why does overflow appears?

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

When I add the **middle** div (the blue one on screenshot), a horizontal scroll bar appears.

I've tried to change the `width` of `divs`, decided to use different measurement units.

Played with `position` values, `display` values.

I'm a beginner, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help me :)

Maybe there is a problem with images in my code? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owHhg.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: hsl(192, 100%, 9%);
  width: 100vw;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  ;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* Header */
header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./images/bg-hero-desktop.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: hsl(193, 100%, 96%);
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-btn {
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 11rem;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  outline: none;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-text {
  margin-top: 8.5rem;
  width: 32rem;
}

.mockups {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.main-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: hsl(322, 100%, 66%);
  width: 14.5rem;
  height: 2.8rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.4rem;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: .2rem .4rem;
}

/* Middle */
.middle {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Huddle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="">
        <button class="nav-btn">Try It Free</button>
      </nav>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="main-text">
          <h1>Built The Community <br> Your Fans Will Love</h1>
          <p>Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities.
          You have a voice, but so does your audience. 
          Create connections with your users as engage in genuine discussion.</p>
          <button class="main-btn">Get Started For Free</button>
        </div>
        <img class="mockups" src="./images/illustration-mockups.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="conv"></div>
    <div class="users"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `width: 100vw;` from the CSS of the body.

Other option is to use `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body.

**Update**

I think the horizontal scroll is present because of the vertical scroll bar, so when you set the width of the body to `100vw` it causes overflow.

With this in mind, you can keep the `width: 100vw;` just set the `max-width: 100%`.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: hsl(192, 100%, 9%);
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2 {
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
}

p {
 font-size: 18px;
}

button {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;;
 font-weight: 700;
}

/* Header */

header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(./images/bg-hero-desktop.svg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: hsl(193, 100%, 96%);
}

.container { 
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 3rem;
}

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-btn {
 font-family: inherit;
 width: 11rem;
 border-radius: 1.2rem;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 outline: none;
}

.main {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-text {
 margin-top: 8.5rem;
 width: 32rem;

}

.mockups {
 margin-top: 4rem;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 width: 50%;
}

.main-btn {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: hsl(322, 100%, 66%);
 width: 14.5rem;
 height: 2.8rem;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 1.4rem;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 margin: .2rem .4rem;
}

/* Middle */

.middle {
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Huddle</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <nav>
    <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="">
    <button class="nav-btn">Try It Free</button>
   </nav>
   <div class="main">
    <div class="main-text">
     <h1>Built The Community <br> Your Fans Will Love</h1>
     <p>Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience. Create connections with your users as engage in genuine discussion.</p>
     <button class="main-btn">Get Started For Free</button>
    </div>
    <img class="mockups" src="./images/illustration-mockups.svg" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="middle">
  <div class="grow"></div>
  <div class="conv"></div>
  <div class="users"></div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing "width" of the body actually helped. Could you tell why is that happened? Is it something with padding, or viewport features?

Comment: Of course, I think the horizontal scroll is present because of the vertical scroll, so when you set the width of the body to `100vw` it will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Add  this to css

```
   body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```